# how to insert string[] data in the access database, how to get this data back

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2007, multiline, arrays

I have a table with films. There is a field with short description.

Using **MEMO** field in Access(is that correct?).
Then I'm adding from **TextBox** that have **multiple lines** some info.
After adding no errors, but in this field in **DataGridview** there is only **System.String[]**.
What's wrong?
And how to get data back to multilined textbox from that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MEMO field expects a single value, not an array. The default `ToString()` implementation is then used, which will return `"System.String[]"`.

You could store a single string value by joining each array member:

```
string singleString = string.Join("\r\n", textboxLines);
```

But probably the TextBox has a property that returns the data as a single string, too.

Comment: That property is simple textBox.Text - there will be all lines separated by '\r\n'

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the differences between WinForms controls and the MsAccess ones, thanks for confirming :)